# After 10.10 -> 11.04 upgrade, can only login via Classic (No Effects)

Tags: 11.04, startup, gnome, ati

Yesterday I upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04, everything seemed to go okay until immediately after login: the desktop goes into a "corrupted" looking state (similar to having too high resolution set).  I can see some kind of movement by moving the mouse around/right clicking, and can enter text terminals via ctrl + alt + f1

It does this in both plain "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu Classic", and only seems to login/startup properly with Ubuntu Classic (No Effects).

I have checked my video card (Radeon X600) and run the unity support test which passes with all "yes" results (Unity supported: yes):

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

I have tried re-installing my Ubuntu desktop:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

With no success.

I can workaround for now with Classic (No Effects), but I'd really like to find the root problem.  Any suggestions on what else to try would be appreciated!

Comment: have you got a file called /etc/X11/xorg.conf ? - suggest rename the file and reboot.

Comment: No such file located at /etc/X11/.  Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Here's a few steps I've tried to fix:  installed fglrx, this helped get into classic & "normal" mode's desktop.  After this can't configure dual monitors (won't allow proper resolution for either, forces mirroring for both displays.  Logging out/shutdown/restart causes video corruption issue again and the computer hangs.  I then removed fglrx, re-installed xserver-xorg-video-radeon driver.  Back to only "no effects" mode working, but desktop & dual monitor support works properly again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few steps I've tried to fix: installed fglrx, this helped get into classic & "normal" mode's desktop. After this can't configure dual monitors (won't allow proper resolution for either, forces mirroring for both displays.

Logging out/shutdown/restart causes video corruption issue again and the computer hangs. I then removed fglrx, re-installed xserver-xorg-video-radeon driver. Back to only "no effects" mode working, but desktop & dual monitor support works properly again.

OP solved issue - comment to answer